# Select cell with checked checboxes only

Tags: jquery

Below code selects the first column which I don't want. I want to select `only cells with checkboxes checked`.

I want to do it with `css` selected only in `$("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1)")`. Don't want to use find or process it in a function body.

```
$("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
    $(this)
      .css("background-color", "red")
      .html();
  });
```

**Table**

```
<table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 0</th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="4" />
            </td>
            <td>Row 1 col 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 col 2</td>
            <td>Row 1 col 3</td>
            <td>Row 1 col 4</td>
            <td>Row 1 col 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" checked />
                <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="6" />
            </td>
            <td>Row 2 col 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 col 2</td>
            <td>Row 2 col 3</td>
            <td>Row 2 col 4</td>
            <td>Row 2 col 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="7" />
            </td>
            <td>Row 3 col 1</td>
            <td>Row 3 col 2</td>
            <td>Row 3 col 3</td>
            <td>Row 3 col 4</td>
            <td>Row 3 col 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="9" />
            </td>
            <td>Row 4 col 1</td>
            <td>Row 4 col 2</td>
            <td>Row 4 col 3</td>
            <td>Row 4 col 4</td>
            <td>Row 4 col 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" checked/>
                <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="10" />
            </td>
            <td>Row 5 col 1</td>
            <td>Row 5 col 2</td>
            <td>Row 5 col 3</td>
            <td>Row 5 col 4</td>
            <td>Row 5 col 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) or [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector along with `:checkbox` & `:checked` selectors. Also no need to use `each` since jQuery will do an internal `each` loop already

```js
 $("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1)")
          .has(':checkbox:checked')
          .css("background-color", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 0</th>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 1 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="6" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 2 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="7" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 3 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="9" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 4 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked/>
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="10" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 5 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.has("input[type=checkbox]:checked")`

```js
$("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1)").has("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
  $(this)
    .css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 0</th>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 1 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 1 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="6" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 2 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 2 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="7" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 3 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 3 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="9" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 4 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 4 col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked/>
      <input class="idField" type="hidden" value="10" />
    </td>
    <td>Row 5 col 1</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 2</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 3</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 4</td>
    <td>Row 5 col 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also you can define this event listener for live changes

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function(itm) {
  $("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1)").has("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    $(this)
      .css("background-color", "white");
  });
  $("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1)").has("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    $(this)
      .css("background-color", "red");
  });
})
```

Comment: Note the `html()` call doesn't really make sense since it is not returned to be used for anything

Comment: Thanks, I just modify the selector part of his code. Answer updated! @charlietfl